# Regex group findings of two matches

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm not big fan of regex but this time I think that there is no way to do what i want. Please see my example with real live testing: [(BEGIN @\d+\b.*?ACTION_READLN ~.+?~)](https://regex101.com/r/sR2dT8/2) Consider such raw text data:

```
BEGIN @1011 Text
Text
    ACTION_READLN ~variableName~
Text
END
BEGIN @1012
asdasd
    ACTION_READLN ~someothervariable~
END
BEGIN @1013

asd
END
```

I was able to create regex which finds "BEGIN @(only numbers)" and "ACTION_READLN ~*~"

```
BEGIN @\d+|(ACTION_READLN.~.+~)
```

Now, I want to group first occurrence of BEGIN with first occurrence of ACTION_READLN. How i can do this?

EDIT: Expected results:

```
Group1:
BEGIN @1011
ACTION_READLN ~variableName~

Group2:
BEGIN @1012
ACTION_READLN ~someothervariable~
```

Comment: Is this a language that you're trying to parse?

Comment: Yes, it's weidu scripting. Unknow and nothing interesting for devs.

Comment: You mean [`(BEGIN @\d+\b.*?ACTION_READLN ~.+?~)`](https://regex101.com/r/sR2dT8/2) ?

Comment: @anubhava's pattern works but you have to make sure that you let `.` token also match newlines or else it may not match anything

Comment: @RNar: That's precisely why I have included `s` flag in demo link

Comment: just explicitly stating it if @ALIENQuake did not realize, I know the `s` flag was included

Comment: a nice trick that i saw from @stribizhev before to match all characters including newlines was `[\s\S]`. It matches any character that is a space or is not a space (effectively, all characters possible).

Comment: You cannot get 2 disconnected substrings into one capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `s` flag only in between for dot to consume newlines. [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) will capture needed stuff.

```
$re = '/(BEGIN @\d+)\b(?s:.*?)(ACTION_READLN.*)/';
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eI3wC0/1). With [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) use `PREG_SET_ORDER` to set output mode if desired.

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Captured matches in each `$out` will be elements `[1]` and `[2]`. `[0]` the full match. [Try at eval.in](https://eval.in/465917)

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely help me to get my results using C#